# How to render a polygon with CGAL?

Tags: graphics, cgal

I have my polygon read from a list of points on a text file, this works fine but I was wondering if there is a way to draw the Polygon read or at least the points. I couldn't find anything related on the documentation.

Is gnuplot the only solution? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Geomview`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Geomview/index.html) as mentioned in the documentation. But you will have to write the Polygon to `OFF` format, for which CGAL provides functions similar to [`write_off`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/group__PkgSurface__mesh.html#gafd48074236c82d29e6eb0bd6fd324265) for many of its classes. You will have to open `Geomview` externally. Another option would be to write out a [VTK](https://www.vtk.org/) file and visualize it with [Paraview](https://www.paraview.org/). This is what I use but you will have to write the code to convert from CGAL data structures to VTK data-structures.